# Print every two from a string with x

Tags: string, python-2.7

I will from a string with numbers and words ,than print it , separate every two Len with an x as start.
I have this code:

```
d = "e345a46be5"
for i in d:
    print "x", i[::2],
```

and i come,  x 43c48eaff x 43c48eaff x ..... . I will xe3,x45,xa4,x6b,xe5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The third parameter of the slice is the step size. This means you are taking the first, third, fifth... item.

I think the easiest way to do what you want is to use range:

```
d = "e345a46be5"
for i in range(0, len(d), 2):
    print "x", d[i:i+2]
```

range(start, stop, step) => range(0,5,2) => [0, 2, 4]

Answer (score 0):

This code that should work on python 2.7 and python 3:

```
for i in range(0,len(d),2):
    print ("x", d[i:i+2])
```

Here we use i as an index instead as a specific letter as you did. and range (a,b,2) enables to go through a list starting with a, going to b excluded with step 2.